# An university lecture and a sequence of university lectures?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

An *university lecture* can be a *single event* of at most a few hours on a single day.

I think the term can also refer to a *sequence of the events* described above, typically weekly over multiple months.
But not meant in the sense of multiple separate events, meant to describe the lectures together with higher context and structure

That works fine in most contexts, because they provide enough information to disambiguate them.

But what to use if it is *important, and completely unambiguous*?
I need it to mean a series of events over months with the higher concept included.

I can not easily provide an example. Two parties are involved, and one does not know the context of the other.

Comment: I would definitely understand _a lecture_ to refer to a single talk.

Comment: It's ***A** university lecture*. _University_ begins with /y/, a consonant. The _a/an_ rule depends on sound, not spelling.

Comment: This question needs a great deal of editing and clarification. Contrary to the second sentence, the term *lecture* cannot be used for a sequence of lectures. It is unclear what 'it' in 'if it is important' stands for. Professor Shor's guess that you are describing a lecture series is a reasonable one, but, given how the question is formulated, it is no more than a guess; it could be that you are trying to describe a course.

Comment: @jsw29: You're right ... I was jumping to conclusions. The OP could also be describing a seminar, a weekly colloquium, a course, or a bunch of other things.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually called a lecture series. Wikipedia even has a [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_public_lecture_series) with a list of public lecture series (many of which are titled *XXXXX Lecture Series*, although more are titled *The XXXXX Lectures*).